# Search doesn't work when it has spaces or different type case characters

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a search that partly works but it has some bugs, the first one is that doesn't search the characters that differen in case, for example: `StackOverflow` is not 'Stackoverlow`, but I want to match it even if they differ in casing.

The other problem is that doesn't search the white spaces, as long as is without spaces it works but when I try to search for example: `Stack Overflow`, then it doesn't find the `Stack Overflow` even if it exits.

This search is that made to search all values inside an object. Waiting for better code, let's see!

Here is the code:

```js
const findIn = (arr, query) => {
  return arr.filter((obj) =>
    Object.keys(obj).some((key) => {
      if (typeof obj[key] === 'string') return obj[key].includes(query);
    })
  );
};
```

As requested here is how the object looks:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Your first problem can be solved by normalising both strings, eg by lower or upper casing them. Your second problem is not clear and needs some proper examples

Comment: @Phil you can answer the question with code for the first problem, for the second problem wait me update the answer

Comment: @SanketShah Doing that rn

Comment: @modih65067 no, I'm not going to provide a partial answer. You need to provide a complete question

Comment: @Phil that's all I have, I don't know why spaces aren't working

Comment: Please provide examples of the properties with spaces in them and the query string you're trying to match. I can tell you right away that `"Questions often get closed on Stack Overflow".includes("Stack Overflow")` does indeed return `true` so what are _you_ working with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve your problem by format your string to lowercase and remove spaces and also in your obj.

```
  const findIn = (arr, query) => {
     let queryFormatted = (query.toLowerCase()).trim();
     return arr.filter((obj) =>
       Object.keys(obj).some((key) => {
        if (typeof obj[key] === 'string'){
          return ((obj[key].toLowerCase()).trim()).includes(queryFormatted);
          }
     })
  );
};
```

Comment: can you please Explain your answer

Comment: @ash By the use of toLowerCase you should format your query and object to a string with lower character and next with replace(/\s/g, '') remove spaces from strings

Comment: @ArezouSaremian yes thanks is working for cases but not for spaces.

Comment: Also I have an recommandation from my Eslint: `Array.prototype.some() expects a value to be returned at the end of arrow function.`

Comment: Just needs a `return false` after the `if { ... }`

Comment: @ArezouSaremian shoudln't this be like this: `replace(/\s/g, ' ')`?

Comment: Because the space is not working

Comment: I selected this as right anwser but doesnt't works 100%, the spaces are a bug @ArezouSaremian

Comment: @modih65067 how can anyone answer your question if you don't provide the required information?